# Close windows with `closable: false` in Electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I made an `electron` closable window that has an HTML menu in it, one of the buttons in the page is "New Game" that closes the window using `windowObject.close()` and launches a new window. what I want is to still be able to close the window with `windowObject.close()` while the window's close button is disabled using `closable:false` property in the window's Object, (because the `closable` property prevents `windowObject.close()` from working). Is there a way to keep the close button disabled (I need the frame's title) while being able to keep `windowObject.close()` working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it closable right before you try to close it.

```js
windowObject.closable = true;
windowObject.close();
```